# after search for email in thunderbird, how do I locate the folder?

Tags: thunderbird

I use the Thunderbird email client, and archive hundreds or thousands of messages (really need to clean it out periodically). Sometimes I have a message come in that I want to store with other messages like it, so I search for those messages. But once I've found them, all I can display of their location is the subfolder they're in.

I have an entire tree of folders and messages, so there are scores of subfolders; I can't tell if a given one is in "family" or "expenses" or what. Isn't there any way, once I've completed a search, to tell what the full path to a message's folder is? otherwise all I've got is the name of the folder, which helps some, but isn't all I expect from the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One [workaround](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1058779): select a message in the *Search* dialog, click *Open in Folder* button, and Thunderbird will open the folder tree to the message location. The *Search* dialog does not close, so <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> back to it to check other results.

Advantage: Similar messages in the folder make it easier to follow the conversation thread.

Disadvantage: Until you click the button, the parent folder is unknown.

Note that adding full path is a [long-term request in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=522768).

[image: Open message in folder]